# How do I put a C header into a namespace in C++?

Tags: c++, c, namespaces, header-files

I've created a C header for C++ static-linked library `foo.h`, which looks like this:

```
#ifndef __FOO_H__
#define __FOO_H__

const size_t SOME_CONST = 22;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif /* __cplusplus */

unsigned long foo();
...
void bar();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif /* __cplusplus */

#endif /* __FOO_H__ */
```

I wanted to put it in some namespace in other header `cfoo`. I've written this:

```
#ifndef __CFOO__
#define __CFOO__

namespace foo {
#include "foo.h"
}

#endif /* __CFOO__ */
```

GCC shows no errors and as I test, everything looks ok, but I am still not sure if this is a proper way to create this namespace. Can anybody confirm if this is a good way to do it, or maybe have some suggestions to do it better?

Comment: If it's your code, the namespace should really be in the header; it's declaring what you're making available, and the namespace is really part of that.
If it's a third-party or generated header, then sure, that's a valid way of doing it. But then you'd need to be sure it's C++-safe C; otherwise you'd also have to surround the `#include` with the `extern "C"` construct. And of course, if the header `#include`s any C++ headers (with their own namespace declarations), things will break as well (because they'll get nested in your `foo`).

Comment: Generic warning: Please do not prefix your own symbols with underscores. Symbols beginning with an underscore are reserved for the implementation by both the C and the C++ standard.

Comment: To be strictly pedantic: identifiers beginning with an underscore at global scope, starting with underscore+capitcal letter at any scope, or containing double underscore *anywhere* in your program.

Comment: @Zastai It is my code, but for project reasons, I have to create two different headers - one C-styled with `extern "C"` and second one only for including in C++ files. The C-styled header doesn't include anything.

Comment: I suppose my point would be that if it's acceptable for the "C" header to have the __cplusplus check and extern "C", it sounds like it would be equally acceptable to include a namespace declaration there as well.

Otherwise, if your foo.h has only "pure" C, then having a "foo.hpp", which adds both the namespace and extern block, makes a bit more sense.

Comment: @Zastai Thank you :)